# Is my jQuery Plugin Completely Incompatible with IE8?

Tags: jquery, plugins, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

So I'm using a template for a jQuery plugin and unfortunately it will not work in IE8 and IE compatibility mode.

I'm not sure if the way I'm writing them is compatibile at all or if I'm just missing something?

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>SuperHero Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/SuperSelect.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="test" style="border:1px solid #000;">
<p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>Sup World</p>
</div>

<script>
$('.test').superHero({

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT:

```
// Utility
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function( obj ) {
        function F(){};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    };
}

(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var Super = {
        init: function( options, elem ) {
            var self = this;

            self.elem = elem;
            self.$elem = $( elem );

            if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
                self.duration = options;
            } else {
                // object was passed
                self.duration = options.duration;
            }                       

            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.superHero.options, options );

            self.replaceSelect();

        },

        replaceSelect: function( duration ) {
            var self = this;
            $('.test').hide();
            $('.test').after('<select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>');

        },


    };

    $.fn.superHero = function( options ){
        return this.each(function() {
            var hero = Object.create( Super );

            hero.init( options, this );

            $.data( this, 'superHero', hero);

        });

    };

    $.fn.superHero.options = {
        duration:           5000,   //Milliseconds that each slide remains on screen. Default is 5 seconds.
        transition:         'fade', //How will the slides trascend?
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QWhPL/1/

Comment: I say it's line 12. With that much description of what "will not work", it's got to be line 12. `;)`

Comment: You're referring to: init: function( options, elem ) {?

Comment: I'm referring to the fact you left us to guess what "will not work" is supposed to mean, or even what "will work" does too.

Comment: You know, if you offered a http://jsfiddle.com or some other means to run the script, and gave a better description of what was expected and what was not working, maybe it would be easier to help.

Comment: My apologies http://jsfiddle.net/QWhPL/ there's the jsfiddle. IE9 Compat debug says:

SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
SuperSelect.js, line 40 character 3

The script should hide the div with the border and .after() a select box

Comment: Once I got the fiddle setup correctly, it seems to work the same in FF and IE8/9 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QWhPL/1/

Comment: @AntonioMoore: In your jsFiddle, the code to define `$.fn.superHero` is being called after you call `$('.test').superHero({});`.

Comment: @Rocket - I've fixed that in an update to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QWhPL/1/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Ah, yes you did.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like when you are setting the options, you have a trailing comma after the transition property. IE8 doesn't like trailing commas, update it to:

```
$.fn.superHero.options = {
        duration:           5000,   //Milliseconds that each slide remains on screen. Default is 5 seconds.
        transition:         'fade' //How will the slides trascend?
    };
```

...and it should work.

You also have a trailing comma after the replaceSelect: function declaration that needs removing:

```
replaceSelect: function( duration ) {
            var self = this;
            $('.test').hide();
            $('.test').after('<select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>');

        }
```

Comment: Although "he" is no friend of mine and is not welcome in my home for dinner, [trailing comma o' death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/) I know well, too well. Four score and about five years ago, I did battle with this nefarious, unscrupulous hanging twit, and the pest, the bug, the *beast* nearly won. Too bad I was too clever and had too much time on my hinds. Eventually, surely, the period with the crooked smile would make his windy way back, like a flea or an ant. I wait.

Comment: Ah the trailing comma. It's always the punctuation. Works perfectly! Much appreciated!!